# Access - Field size for numerical field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

With text boxes, you can set field size on how many characters can be entered. 
Is it possible to do this to a numerical field?

Comment: For number field you can set limit. `Minimum` and `Maximum` limit can be entered in a numeric field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
What you can do is to apply a validation rule to your number field in the table.
Like:

```
Len([enter your field name here])<=4
```

Plus a validation message:

```
Number should be 4 digits at most
```

There's other option too like applying a Before Update event in your form that you use to maintain the data.

And another possible option might be to apply a data macro.
Can't help you on that one as my Access version is pretty old.

Comment: So I tried putting this "Expected:Identified" keeps occuring

Comment: Do you use a space in your column name? If so, put is between square brackets. Or you might be using a reserved word. Hard to tell without example ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the format property.  Another option would be to treat the field as a text box and the format property.  Then when you want to use the value numerically use the val function.